# How do I interpret two 32-bit unsigned integers as a 64-bit floating-point ("double") value?

Tags: matlab

My knowledge of matlab is very limited, so I'll use more general terms to explain my problem:

We have a recording system that samples variables in an embedded system in realtime, and delivers the recorded data as matlab files for analysis.

My problem is that if a recorded variable is a "double" (more specifically a 64-bit, IEEE 754-1985, floating point value), the result is delivered as two unsigned 32-bit integers, and I have no idea how to turn it back into a floating-point value in matlab.

For example, if I record the variable `SomeFloat`, which is a double, I will get the recorded data as two sets of data, `SomeFloat1` and `SomeFloat2`. Both are unsigned, 32-bit integers. `SomeFloat1` contains the 32 most significant bits of `SomeFloat`, and `SomeFloat2` contains the 32 least significant bits.

I was hoping to find an existing function for converting it back do a double, I mean something like:

```
MyDouble = MyDreamFunction(SomeFloat1, SomeFloat2)
```

I have not been able to find `MyDreamFunction`, but being new to matlab, I'm not really sure where to look...

So, does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered trying to fix how the recording system is writing its values, as it seems like you are working around a (very annoying) bug or limitation in it?

Comment: @NeilSlater you are absolutely right. Unfortunately, that is not an option for my immediate problem, but I will certainly suggest a change for the recording system.

Comment: @NeilSlater. The OP mentioned _embedded_ system. This may not be so flexible. I work a lot with 8051 micro controllers and the damn thing is 8 bits. I record 16 and 32 bits values but when I transfer that to the PC it is only 8 bits at a time. So I constantly have to use `typecast` (as in @LuisMendo's answer just below) to rebuild my values once they reach the PC (_and to make things worse, the 8051 send me values in big endian ordering, so i also have to buffer then shuffle the bytes... pffff_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`typecast`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) (convert datatypes without changing underlying data):

```
>> x1 = uint32(7346427); %// example uint32 value
>> x2 = uint32(1789401); %// example uint32 value
>> typecast([x2 x1],'double')
ans =
  1.4327e-306
>> typecast([x1 x2],'double')
ans =
  3.7971e-308
```

Comment: `typecast` is definitely the way to go. It takes all the hassle of having to do the odd multiplications by 2^n for you.

Comment: Yup, this is it - thanks, Luis!
We only got garbage when we first tried it, but as it turned out, it was the data that was corrupt. Seems like there was a one-bit misalignment in the data definition, meaning that the 32+32 bits that are supposed to be our double is actually 63 bits from the actual double, and one bit from a neighboring data field.
When they fix that we might even get a double from start :)

Comment: @Boise Glad I could help! And yes, working so close to the hardware always has that kind of difficulties